# addEventListener to range input slider to show other element

Tags: javascript

For a project I need to display an element only after the slider has been touched/moved. My javascript skills are very limited, and I tried a lot of different things but it never worked.

Here is a link to the js fiddle (test_id is the element I want to display once the slider has been touched/moved): 
https://jsfiddle.net/dominikmeier/5r1Lnsyz/#&togetherjs=5B6pFpLVQ5

```
<div class="form-group required">
   <label class="col-form-label" for="id_kept">Slider:</label>
   <div class="controls  field-offer">
      <div class="input-group slider" data-slider>
          <input type="range" name="kept" value="-1" step="1" min="0" max="10" required id="id_kept" class="form-control" />
          <div class="input-group-append">
             <span class="input-group-text" data-slider-value title="current value" id="front_stagger_output_s" />
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="test" id = "test_id">
   test
</div>
```

Sorry for the "beginner" question but I tried the whole day and couldn't find an answer. Thanks for you help!

Comment: So bind a change event

Comment: sorry i forgot to post the javascript and css code, but both are in the jsfiddle

Comment: Well look at the developer console. Error message in red `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: If you don't mind the value no to be changed try this https://jsfiddle.net/8xdob6av/3/
Otherwise, bind a change event instead of mouseup/touchend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the "mouseup" event on your range slider:

```
/* On your js script */
var range_slider = document.getElementById("id_kept");

range_slider.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    if (this.value > 0) {
        //alert("Range Slider has value of " + this.value);
        document.getElementById("test_id").style.display = 'block';

    } else{
        //alert("Range Slider has value of " + this.value);
        document.getElementById("test_id").style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I deleted the if else statement and now it's exactly what I was looking for